# AWS SSL Certificate for LAMP Application Hosted on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssl, lamp

I am new to AWS, have hosted a PHP Application on Ubuntu(AWS - Free Tier).

I have obtained a SSL using Certificate Manager. I would like to use that for the site.

I installed a self signed certificate, and is reflecting, but unable to use the SSL provided by AWS. I tried using Load Balancer, but unable to install that certificate.

Comment: How are you trying to install the certificate in Load Balancer? And what err are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment the domain should point to the C-Name of the load balancer which in your case is not happening. You have to point the Domain to the Load balancer C-name by changing the DNS. Once that DNS points to the load balancer then it will start serving the SSL certificate as your SSL certificate was added to the ELB.

Comment: Domain is registered on GoDaddy, I should use Route 53 or i can directly edit in DNS settings of GoDaddy?

Comment: I just edited CNAME record of www and pointed to DNS name provided by AWS! Am I correct?

Comment: Yes you added C-Name pointing to the Load Balancer endpoint right?

Comment: Thats correct. I have added DNS name as in LoadBalancer AWS Console. Eagerly Waiting for reflection!

Comment: It will take like 2-3 hrs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117528/discussion-between-anoop-pete-and-error2007s).